# Issues running macro over all files in folder with "Selection"

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have this MS Word macro to run over all files docx in folder (without open them since Visible=false) and call another macro for each file.

The second macro called is "Sub ApplyFormat()" and as you can see, I use `With Selection`, so when the macro calls the 2nd macro it doesn´t make
any changes, I think because my 2nd macro uses "Selection" and to use Selection I think only works if file is opened and visible.

I try to open each document with Visible:=False in order to enhance performance.

How can I fix this? Maybe using some variable instead of "Selection" in my 2nd macro but I don't know how.

Thanks for any help.

```
Sub FormatAllDocxInFolder()
Dim sFolder As String, sFile As String, wdDoc As Document
sFolder = "C:\PATH\TO\FILES"

sFile = Dir(sFolder & "\*.docx", vbNormal)
While sFile <> ""
  Set wdDoc = Documents.Open(FileName:=sFolder & "\" & sFile, AddToRecentFiles:=False, Visible:=False)
  With wdDoc

    Call ApplyFormat

    .Close SaveChanges:=True

  End With
  strFile = Dir()
Wend
Set wdDoc = Nothing
End Sub

Sub ApplyFormat()
    Selection.HomeKey wdStory
    With Selection.Find
        .ClearFormatting
        .Replacement.ClearFormatting
        .Text = "abc"
        .Replacement.Text = " def"
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your "(without open them since Visible=false)" assumption is incorrect - the files *are* being opened. However, since Visible=False, nothing is being selected. Accordingly, you need to (and should, anyway) work with the document directly, as in:

```
Sub FormatAllDocxInFolder()
Dim sFolder As String, sFile As String, wdDoc As Document
sFolder = "C:\PATH\TO\FILES"

sFile = Dir(sFolder & "\*.docx", vbNormal)
While sFile <> ""
  Set wdDoc = Documents.Open(FileName:=sFolder & "\" & sFile, AddToRecentFiles:=False, Visible:=False)
  Call ApplyFormat(wdDoc)
  wdDoc.Close SaveChanges:=True
  sFile = Dir()
Wend
Set wdDoc = Nothing
End Sub

Sub ApplyFormat(wdDoc As Document)
With wdDoc.Range.Find
  .ClearFormatting
  .Replacement.ClearFormatting
  .Text = "abc"
  .Replacement.Text = " def"
  .Wrap = wdFindContinue
  .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
End With
End Sub
```

In any event, your code could be reduced to:

```
Sub FormatAllDocxInFolder()
Dim sFolder As String, sFile As String, wdDoc As Document
sFolder = "C:\PATH\TO\FILES"

sFile = Dir(sFolder & "\*.docx", vbNormal)
While sFile <> ""
  Set wdDoc = Documents.Open(FileName:=sFolder & "\" & sFile, AddToRecentFiles:=False, Visible:=False)
  With wdDoc
    With .Range.Find
        .ClearFormatting
        .Replacement.ClearFormatting
        .Text = "abc"
        .Replacement.Text = " def"
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
    End With
    .Close SaveChanges:=True
  End With
  sFile = Dir()
Wend
Set wdDoc = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: macropod,Thanks for your help. I've tried as you mentioned using `wdDoc.Range`  but works in some cases and in other doesn´t. The issue is that I need to call 4 macros and when I replace `Selection` with `wdDoc.Range` or with `wdDoc.Content` the following commands don´t work `<< Selection.HomeKey wdStory Selection.WholeStory >> , <<Selection.MoveDown Unit:=wdLine, Count:=1 >>`

Comment: Working with Selection is incredibly inefficient and is rarely needed. With references like wdDoc.Range you won't need code like Selection.HomeKey wdStory - you'll see the code I posted doesn't have it - and probably don't need Selection.WholeStory, since wdDoc.Range refers to exactly the same content. As for Selection.MoveDown, without knowing what you're trying to do, it's impossible to say how the code should be modified.

Comment: I use `Selection.WholeStory` (Using macro recorder) when I go to "Line and Paragraph Spacing/Line Spacing Options" and then "Don´t add space between paragraphs of the same style". 
Regarding `Selection.MoveDown`, I `Find` a letter then I select the whole paragraphs of that letter to change the `Font.Name`. Then I use "move down" to assure I go to next line and `.HomeKey` to go to beginning of the line. Probably those steps could be achieved in better way.

Comment: You're clearly misusing Word when you do this. Fonts and paragraph spacing should be managed via the corresponding Styles, not by crudely overwriting the existing Styles with direct formatting - your current approach causes bloated documents and can lead to document corruption.

Comment: macropod, it seems for what you say I'm going by the wrong way. So, to follow your example using `wdDoc.Range`, how would be the correct way to change the Font name, Font color to the current paragraph when is matched doing this?: `With wdDoc.Range.Find .Font.Size = 14: .Text = "?" .Execute End With` And how would be the way to and remove extra spaces between paragraphs of the same style? If you think is out of the scope, I need to open a question for that specific issue. Thanks

Comment: Your formatting issues really have nothing to do with the Find/Replace discussion with which this thread started. Kindly start a new thread for the formatting issues.

Answer (score 1):

issues found with the code

1. `strFile = Dir()` used instead of `sFile = Dir()`
2. Either `WdDoc` document object to be passed as an argument to `Sub ApplyFormat`   Or the Code chunk is to be directly used in the file loop

it worked Like this

```
Sub FormatAllDocxInFolder()
Dim sFolder As String, sFile As String, wdDoc As Document
sFolder = "C:\Users\user\desktop\folder1\"

sFile = Dir(sFolder & "\*.docx", vbNormal)
While sFile <> ""
  Set wdDoc = Documents.Open(FileName:=sFolder & "\" & sFile, AddToRecentFiles:=False, Visible:=False)
  With wdDoc
    Call ApplyFormat(wdDoc)
    .Close SaveChanges:=True
  End With
  sFile = Dir
Wend
Set wdDoc = Nothing
End Sub
Sub ApplyFormat(Xdoc As Document)
    With Xdoc.Content.Find
        .ClearFormatting
        .Replacement.ClearFormatting
        .Text = "abc"
        .Replacement.Text = " def"
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: @Ahmed_AU Thanks for your help. I've tried as you mentioned using `wdDoc.Content` but works in some cases and in other doesn´t. The issue is that I need to call 4 macros and when I replace `Selection` with `wdDoc.Range` or with `wdDoc.Content` the following commands don´t work `<< Selection.HomeKey wdStory Selection.WholeStory >> , << Selection.MoveDown Unit:=wdLine, Count:=1 >>`